# DBVisualizer Unicode Bug

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, dbvisualizer

I am facing a problem while inserting two characters `(É (0xC389) and П (0xD0BF))` in database table that has Charset UTF-8<strike>.and Collation UTF-8 as well. These both characters come in range `U+0800 - U+FFFF`. So, I understand that these two characters require [16 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)</strike>.

Strange thing is, `É (0xC389)` is being inserted in the table from DBVisualizer and being displayed normal but `П (0xD0BF)` is not saved properly. I first thought, may be it's client issue but why it happens with 1 character that lies in the same range as the other one?

I am really amazed with the behaviour. So, I don't understand, if my understanding about UTF-8 is wrong or it is really a DBVisualizer bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Note: Codepoints between U+0800 and U+FFFF are encoded as 24 bits (3 bytes) in UTF-8.

Comment: @RandomGuy32 It does require 24 bits but 8 bits are reserved, so can only use 16 bits, out of those 24

Comment: Please provide a couple more mis-rendered characters; maybe I can find a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is wrong.

Are you looking at a mixture of Latin and Cyrillic?  Or Hangul?

```
UTF-8 Hex    Unicode  Visible    Meaning
C389        201=x00C9   É        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
D09F       1055=x041F   П        CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER PE
EC8E89          xC389   쎉       HANGUL SYLLABLE SSENJ
ED82BF          xD0BF   킿       HANGUL SYLLABLE KIH
```

That is, `É` is Unicode `U+00C9` ("codepoint 201"), and is encoded as hex `C389` when used in text.  (Etc)

The first two require 16 bits in UTF-8; the other two need 24 bits.  This is also the case for MySQL's `CHARACTER SET` utf8 or utf8mb4.

See if you can get DBVisualizer to talk UTF-8, not Unicode.

Comment: Updated my question. These were actually hexa values, not Unicode. Also, I have set DBVisualizer settings to UTF-8 but not any change.

Comment: `É` is _not_ Unicode C389, it is UTF-8 C389.  Those are _different_.  How does one specify UTF-8 in DBVisualizer?  What technique are you using to discover "C389"?